# Numbered list in python

Tags: python, list

I need to make a numbered list from list elements in python. 
Example list:

```
destinations = ['Los Angeles ', 'Rhodos ', 'Dubai ', 'Manila ', 'Mallorca ', 'New York ']
```

I need to print out elements as numbered list:

```
1. Los Angeles 
2. Rhodos 
3. Dubai 
4. Manila 
5. Mallorca 
6. New York
```

If I do:

```
print ('\n'.join(destinations))
```

It prints out elements on separate lines, but I cannot add numbers.

Answer (score 4):

You simply use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and count from `1`

```
>>> destinations = ['Los Angeles ', 'Rhodos ', 'Dubai ', 'Manila ', 'Mallorca ', 'New York ']  
>>> for index, value in enumerate(destinations, 1):
...     print("{}. {}".format(index, value))
... 
1. Los Angeles 
2. Rhodos 
3. Dubai 
4. Manila 
5. Mallorca 
6. New York
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, dest in enumerate(destinations, 1):
    print(" %d. %s" % (i, dest))
```

Comment: This starts the enumeration at 0. The correct answer is stackoverflow.com/a/37344465/2290151

Comment: I have adjusted my answer to count from 1